# Unable to form Elasticsearch 7 cluster on EC2 machines

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-7

I have following configuration setup on two AWS ec2 machines.

```
    Machine 10.0.66.123
    ----------------------
    cluster.name: uat-es-cluster
    node.name: uat-es-1
    path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
    path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
    network.host: 10.0.66.123
    discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.66.106", "10.0.66.123"]
    cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.66.106", "10.0.66.123"]
    node.master: true


    Machine 10.0.66.106
    ----------------------
    cluster.name: uat-es-cluster
    node.name: uat-es-2
    path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
    path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
    network.host: 10.0.66.106
    discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.0.66.123", "10.0.66.106"]
    cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.66.106", "10.0.66.123"]
    node.master: true
```

I am getting following log on both nodes.

[2019-12-30T10:17:19,037][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [uat-es-2] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [10.0.66.106, 10.0.66.123] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{uat-es-2}{DBRJq4uZSJycu7L6vcmZHw}{9k4Ux2veQFiYZcrnHZmFtg}{10.0.66.106}{10.0.66.106:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=4074115072, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]; discovery will continue using [10.0.66.123:9300] from hosts providers and [{uat-es-2}{DBRJq4uZSJycu7L6vcmZHw}{9k4Ux2veQFiYZcrnHZmFtg}{10.0.66.106}{10.0.66.106:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=4074115072, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0

Answer (score 1):

I was missing inbound rule for TCP, port `9300` in ec2 instance's security group.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the following into your elasticsearch.yml of your master node.

cluster.initial_master_nodes:
- node_name_or_ip

Start the first node and then the rest of the nodes.

Comment: I have already mentioned `cluster.initial_master_nodes` as `["10.0.66.106", "10.0.66.123"]`, do you mean something else?

Comment: try using node names instead ["uat-es-1","uat-es-2"] and restart nodes

Comment: `cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["uat-es-1", "uat-es-2"]` did not work. :(

Comment: and just to confirm the servers can be accessible by node names using the host's file?

Comment: actually I was missing 9300 port inbound rules entry in security group of ec2 instance. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: glad its working please vote for the answer for the help made, thanks